# Wordpress post-template null warnings

Tags: php, pages, templates, page-template, id

I am getting these PHP8.0 Warnings from my WordPress site. The warnings are pointing to core code, not anything custom. When I turn debugging on there are no error messages on the site. I also checked the menu and all of the links are accurate. Is anyone able to help me figure out this warning?

```
[09-Jan-2024 19:21:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in \wp-includes\post-template.php on line 674

[09-Jan-2024 19:21:27 UTC] PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in \wp-includes\post-template.php on line 675
```

```
    if ( is_singular() ) {
        $post      = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $post_id   = $post->ID; // Line 674
        $post_type = $post->post_type; // Line 675
```

Comment: For some reason the `$post` variable is missing on a single post template. Does this error appear on particular pages? Are you doing anything unusual in custom code that would affect the `$post` variable? Are you creating some kind of custom route/endpoint that doesn't point to a post?

Comment: Ah, it seems the error was showing when you get the 404 error message. I created a custom 404 error page and the error is now gone. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

The error was occurring when someone hits a page that doesn't exist (404). I created a custom 404 error page and the errors are now gone.